# Charging series / parallel 18650 battery pack

Tags: battery-charging

I have a 18650 battery cell configured as 4 pairs in parallel
wired in series for 16 volts.  I first CC/CV charged the
paralleled pairs to 4 volts each and stopped the charge 
at 50mA.  I would like to know if the same CC amperage should be used in this configuration as for a single cell   Each cell is 3.7 volt 2200mAh CC=1200mAh.

Answer (score 1):

The CC current of the four pairs of cells (each pair connected in parallel) connected in series should be the same as the current for one pair of cells in parallel or twice the current for a single cell.

The CV level, on the other side, should be 4 times the voltage for a single pair or for a single cell.

Comment: Many thanks, I was not sure about the CC current, worked perfectly.

Comment: I’m glad it worked. Always be aware that the 4 pairs need to be balanced during charging to avoid overcharging of any particular pair, what can be dangerous.